# Convert traits for std error types are typically missing

Tags: rust

It is quite common that the `?` operator results in errors. For instance, a function with return type `Result<u32, &'static str>` may result in an error like:

```
file.read(&mut buffer)?;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<std::io::Error>` is not implemented for `&str`
```

A mismatch between the function return type and the returned error requires a conversion. However, traits are sometimes not available. That makes the `?` operator inconvenient and force things like using `match`, etc. a lot.

What is the typical return type that allows for automatic conversion of the most common std error types?

Comment: I think that you did not understand the purpose of the `?` operator. It is not intended to convert anything. Change the return type of your function to `io::Error`, and everything will be ok.

Comment: I do understand the operator and it is not about converting. It will unpack, but there must be a trait available to a conversion to happen if I want a more general error type in result.

Comment: You should try to improve the wording of the question: as in, it is not very clear.

Comment: @Boiethios *It is not intended to convert anything* — one of the biggest benefits of `?` is that it **does** convert the error type for you. It cannot write the implementations of those conversions but it can call them. Your own answer makes use of the fact that errors are converted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type that you are looking for is `Box<dyn Error>`. [`std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) is a trait that all error types should implement.

Example with multiple error types:

```
use std::{error::Error, fs::File, io::prelude::*};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut file = File::create("foo.txt")?; // io::Error
    file.write_all(b"Hello, world!")?; // io::Error
    let _: i32 = "123".parse()?; // fmt::Error
    Ok(())
}
```